# How to get a activityindicator stop when the web load already?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a webview and an activityIndicator, I want that the activityIndicator stop when the URL load already. I have this:

```
XYZViewController.h

@interface XYZViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *browser; 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

@end
```

XYZViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"]];

    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [self.browser loadRequest:request];
}

-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    self.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
XYZViewController* viewVC = [XYZViewController alloc]init];

viewVC.browser.delegate = viewVC;
```

I dont know that is wrong?

Anybody help me please?

Comment: What _is_ wrong?  It's hard to tell what your problem is from your question.

Comment: did you actually mark self.browser.delegate = self?

Comment: What makes you think anything is wrong?  At first glance it looks like it should be ok, but it's hard to be sure without a precise statement of what you hope to see and what you're actually seeing that seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what @puzzl suggested and then add it to `webViewDidStartLoad:` as opposed to viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   ... 
   self.browser.delegate = self
   ...
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    self.activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```